# Why will the resources (e.g images) in the jar file be removed when publish android library as AAR to maven repository in Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here is my case.
I have an android library project with some jar file dependencies in 'libs' folder. The jar files contain some images files in it. The image files are in the 'assets' folder in the jar.(e.g. foo.jar/assets/bar.png) When I publish the project to private maven repository (Sonatype Nexus) with the project being built to AAR artifact:
On Android Gradle Plugin 2.2.2, everything is ok.
But when I upgrade to Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0, the images in the jar file is missing, and assets folder is completely removed. It seems like Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 would strip out resources in the jar file.

Here is my Gradle script.

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configurePOM(project, pom)
            repository(url: "http://private-ip") {
                authentication(userName: 'abc', password: 'abc')
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "http://private-ip") {
                authentication(userName: 'abc', password: 'abc')
            }
        }
    }
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    options {
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
        linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
    }
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}


private configurePOM(Project p, def pom) {
    pom.project {
        groupId 'com.xxx.android'
        artifactId p.name
        version "1.0.0"
        name 'com.xxx.android'
        packaging 'aar'
        description "Lib For Android"
        url "http://private-ip"
        inceptionYear "2016"

        licenses {
            license {
                name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
                url "http://xxx"
                distribution "repo"
                comments "A business - friendly OSS license"
            }
        }

        developers {
            developer {
                id "android_team"
                name "android_team"
                email "android_team@xxx.com"
                url "http://xxx"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anybody occur this problem too?  Or any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I'm using Gradle 4.1 and my aar excludes all resources folders from jars dependencies. Did you get clue to handle this

Comment: @DenisVolohsin not yet.  I'm stuck on this problem for a long time.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: @Naz_Jnr  not yet.